# How to disable <select> based on other <select> on Select2.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, is-empty, disabled-input

i'm having a little trouble with disabling a "select" input.

I need to disable "cidade" whenever nothing is selected on "estado".

here's my code:

```
<select id="estado" class="select_customized">
    <option></option>
    <option value="sp">São Paulo</option>
    <option value="mg">Minas Gerais</option>
    <option value="rj">Rio de Janeiro</option>

</select>

<select id="cidade" class="select_customized">
     <option></option>
     <option value="sao-paulo">São Paulo</option>
     <option value="minas-gerais">Minas Gerais</option>
     <option value="rio-de-janeiro">Rio de Janeiro</option>

</select>
```

And here's the script i'm using:

```
$("#cidade").select2("enable", false); 

    $("#estado").on('change',function(){

    var is_empty = $('#estado').is(":empty");

        if(is_empty){

            $("#cidade").select2("enable", false); 

        }

        else {

            $("#cidade").select2("enable", true); 

        }

    });
```

this kinda works, but whenever i choose something on the "estado" input, and clear it again, "cidade" does not disable again... any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the select2 call to check if the selection box is empty, instead of going into the original #estado box you created (since that is hidden by select2).

Your call:

```
var is_empty = $('#estado').is(":empty");
```

then can be changed to something like:

```
var is_empty = $('#estado').select2("val") == "";
```

and that did the job for me. Note that the actual comparison above will differ a bit depending on for example if you are using a multi-valued selection box.

Answer (score 2):

I think is that you need actually. You just need to set the .on('change') to make it works, like this fiddle.

UPDATE: easier than I thought.

http://jsfiddle.net/fczo7tLq/2/

```
$("#cidade").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
$("#estado").on('change', function() {
    var that = $("#estado option:selected").val();
    if (that !== "empty") {
        $("#cidade").prop('disabled', false);
    } else { 
         $("#cidade").prop('disabled', 'disabled');        
    }


});
```